# MySQLi Query not working, correct Syntax?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Hi everyone so I have 3 tables: invoices, customers and invoice items however it does not seem to be grabbing my data, anyone have any ideas on it?

> string(216) "SELECT * FROM invoices as i JOIN customers as c ON c.invoice = i.invoice JOIN invoice_items as p ON p.invoice = i.invoice WHERE i.invoice = 1000 ORDER BY i.invoice " NULL Errormessage:

From:

```
var_dump($query);
var_dump($resutls);

printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
```

QUERY:

```
SELECT *
         FROM invoices as i 
                  JOIN customers as c ON c.invoice = i.invoice
                  JOIN invoice_items as p ON p.invoice = i.invoice
         WHERE i.invoice = ".$getID."
                  ORDER BY i.invoice
```

PHP

```
    <?php
include('includes/config.php');
include('header.php');
include('functions.php');

$getID = $_GET['id'];

// Connect to the database
$mysqli = new mysqli(DATABASE_HOST, DATABASE_USER, DATABASE_PASS, DATABASE_NAME);

// output any connection error
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Error : ('.$mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
}

// the query
$query = "SELECT *
     FROM invoices i,customers c,invoice_items p where
     c.invoice = i.invoice and p.invoice = i.invoice and
     i.invoice = '".$getID."' ORDER BY i.invoice";

// mysqli select query
$results = $mysqli->query($query);

// mysqli select query
if($results) {

    while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
        //var_dump($row['customer_name']);
        $customer_name = $row['customer_name']; // customer name
        $customer_email = $row['customer_email']; // customer email
        $customer_address_1 = $row['customer_address_1']; // customer address
        $customer_address_2 = $row['customer_address_2']; // customer address
        $customer_town = $row['customer_town']; // customer town
        $customer_county = $row['customer_county']; // customer county
        $customer_postcode = $row['customer_postcode']; // customer postcode
        $customer_phone = $row['customer_phone']; // customer phone number

        //shipping
        $customer_name_ship = $row['customer_name_ship']; // customer name (shipping)
        $customer_address_1_ship = $row['customer_address_1_ship']; // customer address (shipping)
        $customer_address_2_ship = $row['customer_address_2_ship']; // customer address (shipping)
        $customer_town_ship = $row['customer_town_ship']; // customer town (shipping)
        $customer_county_ship = $row['customer_county_ship']; // customer county (shipping)
        $customer_postcode_ship = $row['customer_postcode_ship']; // customer postcode (shipping)

        // invoice details
        $invoice_number = $row['invoice_id']; // invoice number
        $invoice_date = $row['invoice_date']; // invoice date
        $invoice_due_date = $row['invoice_due_date']; // invoice due date
        $invoice_subtotal = $row['invoice_subtotal']; // invoice sub-total
        $invoice_shipping = $row['invoice_shipping']; // invoice shipping amount
        $invoice_discount = $row['invoice_discount']; // invoice discount
        $invoice_vat = $row['invoice_vat']; // invoice vat
        $invoice_total = $row['invoice_total']; // invoice total
        $invoice_notes = $row['invoice_notes']; // Invoice notes
        $invoice_status = $row['invoice_status']; // Invoice status
    }
}

?>

        <h1>Edit Invoice (<?php echo $getID; ?>)</h1>
        <hr>

        <div id="response" class="alert alert-success" style="display:none;">
            <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
            <div class="message"></div>
        </div>

        <form method="post" id="create_invoice">
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="create_invoice">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-5">
                    <h1>
                        <img src="<?php echo COMPANY_LOGO ?>" class="img-responsive">
                    </h1>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-7 text-right">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-9">
                            <h1>INVOICE</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3">
                            <select name="invoice_status" id="invoice_status" class="form-control">
                                <option value="open" <?php if($invoice_status == "open"){?>selected<?php } ?>>Open</option>
                                <option value="paid" <?php if($invoice_status == "paid"){?>selected<?php } ?>>Paid</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 no-padding-right">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="input-group date" id="invoice_date">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control required" name="invoice_date" placeholder="Select invoice date" data-date-format="<?php echo DATE_FORMAT ?>" value="<?php echo $invoice_date; ?>" />
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="input-group date" id="invoice_due_date">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control required" name="invoice_due_date" placeholder="Select due date" data-date-format="<?php echo DATE_FORMAT ?>" value="<?php echo $invoice_due_date; ?>" />
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group col-xs-4 float-right">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">#<?php echo INVOICE_PREFIX ?></span>
                        <input type="text" name="invoice_id" id="invoice_id" class="form-control required" placeholder="Invoice Number" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1" value="<?php echo $getID; ?>">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4>Customer Information</h4>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body form-group form-group-sm">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control margin-bottom copy-input required" name="customer_name" id="customer_name" placeholder="Enter name" tabindex="1" value="<?php echo $customer_name; ?>">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control margin-bottom copy-input required" name="customer_address_1" id="customer_address_1" placeholder="Address 1" tabindex="3" value="<?php echo $customer_address_1; ?>">    
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control margin-bottom copy-input required" name="customer_town" id="customer_town" placeholder="Town" tabindex="5" value="<?php echo $customer_town; ?>">        
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group no-margin-bottom">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control copy-input required" name="customer_postcode" id="customer_postcode" placeholder="Postcode" tabindex="7" value="<?php echo $customer_postcode; ?>">                  
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <div class="input-group float-right margin-bottom">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">@</span>
                                        <input type="email" class="form-control copy-input required" name="customer_email" id="customer_email" placeholder="E-mail address" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1" tabindex="2" value="<?php echo $customer_email; ?>">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control margin-bottom copy-input" name="customer_address_2" id="customer_address_2" placeholder="Address 2" tabindex="4" value="<?php echo $customer_address_2; ?>">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control margin-bottom copy-input required" name="customer_county" id="customer_county" placeholder="County" tabindex="6" value="<?php echo $customer_county; ?>">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group no-margin-bottom">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control required" name="customer_phone" id="invoice_phone" placeholder="Phone number" tabindex="8" value="<?php echo $customer_phone; ?>">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 text-right">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4>Shipping Information</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body form-group form-group-sm">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control margin-bottom required" name="customer_name_ship" id="customer_name_ship" placeholder="Enter name" tabindex="9" value="<?php echo $customer_name_ship; ?>">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control margin-bottom" name="customer_address_2_ship" id="customer_address_2_ship" placeholder="Address 2" tabindex="11" value="<?php echo $customer_address_2_ship; ?>">    
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group no-margin-bottom">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control required" name="customer_county_ship" id="customer_county_ship" placeholder="County" tabindex="13" value="<?php echo $customer_county_ship; ?>">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control margin-bottom required" name="customer_address_1_ship" id="customer_address_1_ship" placeholder="Address 1" tabindex="10" value="<?php echo $customer_address_1_ship; ?>">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control margin-bottom required" name="customer_town_ship" id="customer_town_ship" placeholder="Town" tabindex="12" value="<?php echo $customer_town_ship; ?>">                           
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group no-margin-bottom">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control required" name="customer_postcode_ship" id="customer_postcode_ship" placeholder="Postcode" tabindex="14" value="<?php echo $customer_postcode_ship; ?>">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- / end client details section -->
            <table class="table table-bordered" id="invoice_table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th width="500">
                            <h4><a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-xs add-row"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span></a> Item</h4>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <h4>Qty</h4>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <h4>Price</h4>
                        </th>
                        <th width="300">
                            <h4>Discount</h4>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <h4>Sub Total</h4>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                        foreach($invoice_product as $key => $value) {
                            $item_product = $value;
                            // $item_description = $_POST['invoice_product_desc'][$key];
                            $item_qty = $row['invoice_product_qty'][$key];
                            $item_price = $row['invoice_product_price'][$key];
                            $item_discount = $row['invoice_product_discount'][$key];
                            $item_subtotal = $row['invoice_product_sub'][$key];
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group form-group-sm  no-margin-bottom">
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete-row"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control form-group-sm item-input invoice_product" name="invoice_product[]" placeholder="Enter item title and / or description" value="<?php echo $item_product; ?>">
                                <p class="item-select">or <a href="#">select an item</a></p>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-right">
                            <div class="form-group form-group-sm no-margin-bottom">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control calculate" name="invoice_product_qty[]" value="1" value="<?php echo $item_qty; ?>">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-right">
                            <div class="input-group input-group-sm  no-margin-bottom">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><?php echo CURRENCY ?></span>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control calculate invoice_product_price required" name="invoice_product_price[]" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1" placeholder="0.00" value="<?php echo $item_price; ?>">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-right">
                            <div class="form-group form-group-sm  no-margin-bottom">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control calculate" name="invoice_product_discount[]" placeholder="Enter % or value (ex: 10% or 10.50)" value="<?php echo $item_discount; ?>">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-right">
                            <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><?php echo CURRENCY ?></span>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control calculate-sub" name="invoice_product_sub[]" id="invoice_product_sub" value="0.00" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1" value="<?php echo $item_subtotal; ?>" disabled>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php } ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div id="invoice_totals" class="padding-right row text-right">
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <div class="input-group form-group-sm textarea no-margin-bottom">
                        <textarea class-"form-control" name="invoice_notes" placeholder="Please enter any order notes here." value="<?php echo $invoice_notes; ?>"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 no-padding-right">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-6">
                            <strong>Sub Total:</strong>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3">
                            <?php echo CURRENCY ?><span class="invoice-sub-total"> <?php echo $invoice_subtotal; ?></span>
                            <input type="hidden" name="invoice_subtotal" id="invoice_subtotal" value="<?php echo $invoice_subtotal; ?>">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-6">
                            <strong>Discount:</strong>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3">
                            <?php echo CURRENCY ?><span class="invoice-discount"> <?php echo $invoice_discount; ?></span>
                            <input type="hidden" name="invoice_discount" id="invoice_discount" value="<?php echo $invoice_discount; ?>">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-6">
                            <strong class="shipping">Shipping:</strong>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3">
                            <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><?php echo CURRENCY ?></span>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control calculate shipping" name="invoice_shipping" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1" placeholder="0.00" value="<?php echo $invoice_shipping; ?>">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php if (ENABLE_VAT == true) { ?>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-6">
                            <strong>TAX/VAT:</strong>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3">
                            <?php echo CURRENCY ?><span class="invoice-vat" data-enable-vat="<?php echo ENABLE_VAT ?>" data-vat-rate="<?php echo VAT_RATE ?>" data-vat-method="<?php echo VAT_INCLUDED ?>">0.00</span>
                            <input type="hidden" name="invoice_vat" id="invoice_vat">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-6">
                            <strong>Total:</strong>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3">
                            <?php echo CURRENCY ?><span class="invoice-total"> <?php echo $invoice_total; ?></span>
                            <input type="hidden" name="invoice_total" id="invoice_total" value="<?php echo $invoice_total; ?>">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 margin-top btn-group">
                    <input type="submit" id="action_edit_invoice" class="btn btn-success float-right" value="Update Invoice" data-loading-text="Updating...">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>

        <div id="insert" class="modal fade">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Select an item</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <?php popProductsList(); ?>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary" id="selected">Add</button>
                <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Cancel</button>
              </div>
            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
          </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
        </div><!-- /.modal -->

<?php
    include('footer.php');
?>
```

Comment: So what is the issue?

Comment: Is the variable actually $resutls?

Comment: what is the data type of the field i.invoice??

Comment: Problem is its not returning the results from the ID i specify - i've added the PHP as well, when i try to echo one shows nothing - from debug its coming back as NULL

Comment: Just as an aside, "WHERE i.invoice = 1000 ORDER BY i.invoice" is a bit silly, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

```
SELECT p.*, i.*, c.*
FROM invoice_items p 
JOIN invoices i ON i.invoice = p.invoice
JOIN customers c ON c.invoice = i.invoice
WHERE p.invoice = '" . $mysqli->real_escape_string($getID) . "'
```

Please make sure that:
`i.invoice`, `c.invoice` and `p.invoice` exists and has an index on each table

PS: This query will return multiple entries depending on how many invoice_items are stored for the selected invoice

Comment: Its returning them all in mysql now which is great, do you see why its not showing on the page though? with my echo's ? the dates seem to show at the top but thats it, not other values and product not looping (this part might be wrong anyway)

Comment: how many rows are returned? With your code you always replace the assigned values with the last entry returned.. you must consider putting the invoice items inside the while loop.. If there is only an entry returned then you don't need a while loop.. you can assign the row directly as: `$row = $results->fetch_assoc();`

Comment: when i put in mysql i get 2 rows as 2 products on invoice, my issue is nothing is showing on frontend and no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this query

```
SELECT *
     FROM invoices i,customers c,invoice_items p where
     c.invoice = i.invoice and p.invoice = i.invoice and
     i.invoice = '".$getID."' ORDER BY i.invoice


if ($mysqli->query("SELECT *
     FROM invoices i,customers c,invoice_items p where
     c.invoice = i.invoice and p.invoice = i.invoice and
     i.invoice = '".$getID."' ORDER BY i.invoice") === TRUE) {
printf("No Error Message.\n");
}
```

Comment: Does not seem to be doing trick, when i dump $results comes back as NULL

Comment: can you check with the above condition so that we can get to know the where the issue was?

Comment: Does not show anything, it does seem to display the dates but thats all, ill update with full html as well

Comment: have you placed the query in phpmyadmin?.....did you get any error after placing the query in phpmyadmin?

Comment: It brings back invoice data and customer data, no product data and its bringing it back twice for some reason - wonder why my echo does not show the values on those though.

Comment: can you place your query in mysql_fetch_assoc($results)

Answer (score 0):

Try run the query directly in database console to see if you can get results. If not, you need check your data.

Also you are using direct input to build your query, which is dangerous. You need somehow convert the getid to make sure it's a number and only a number.